# Batch conversion of PDF files to PDF/A files

Tags: windows, pdf, archiving

I am looking for a program, user script or web tool that can perform batch conversion of PDF files to [PDF/A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) files. It should run on Microsoft Windows. Ideally it should give some warnings if something gets messed up during the conversion.

Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Adobe Acrobat.

Check this page for the instructions: [batch conversion to pdfa](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/05/batch_conversion_to_pdfa/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517141850/http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2007/05/batch_conversion_to_pdfa/)).

Screenshot of the page:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[PDF/A Manager](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfamanager/index.html) from PDFTron is a command line tool for full PDF/A automation. Both automatic conversion, and validation.

https://www.pdftron.com/pdfamanager/index.html

- Linux, Mac OS X, Microsoft Windows
- command line
- non-free but free trial
- Supports both PDF/A-1a and PDF/A-1b.
- Last version was released on March 27, 2009 (Version 1.0)